# Row con elementos que se muestran con hover

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

Estoy intentando crear un menú en WordPress diferentes a los que se pueden crear a través de Appareance>Menus.

Para ello, he creado una **row** de 4 columnas como este:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Element1, Element2, "Tell us your needs" y "Latest news" son los elementos principales y SubElement1, SubElement2 y SubElement3 salen de Element1.

Con el siguiente **código** en Layout CSS, he conseguido que los SubElement permanezcan escondidos hasta que posiciono el cursor encima de Element1, pero al hacerlo **sólo me muestra el SubElement1**.

```css
#main-element1-subelement1{
    display: none;
}
#main-element1-subelement2{
    display: none;
}
#main-element1-subelement3{
    display: none;
}


#main-element1:hover + #main-element1-subelement1{
    display: block;
}
#main-element1-subelement1:hover{
    display: block;
}

#main-element1:hover + #main-element1-subelement2{
    display: block;
}
#main-element1-subelement2:hover{
    display: block;
}

#main-element1:hover + #main-element1-subelement3{
    display: block;
}
#main-element1-subelement3:hover{
    display: block;
}
```

**Necesito que se muestren los cuatro Subelement al posicionarme encima de Element1 pero no doy con el errór.**

**Aclaración:**

Dentro de Element1:

[image: HTML Element de Element1]

Dentro de cada SubElement:

[image: HTML Element de SubElement1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prueba cambiando esto:

```css
#main-element1:hover + #main-element1-subelement1{
    display: block;
}
```

por esto:

```css
#main-element1:hover ~ main{
    display: block;
}
```

Aquí te dejo un snippet de ejemplo, con los dos casos posibles que se me ocurren, pues no has puesto tu HTML y desconozco si tu div inicial contiene el resto (con lo que el símbolo seria `>`) o son hermanos (con lo que el símbolo es `~`).

```css
#main-element1-subelement1{
    display: none;
}
#main-element1-subelement2{
    display: none;
}
#main-element1-subelement3{
    display: none;
}

#main-element2-subelement1{
    display: none;
}
#main-element2-subelement2{
    display: none;
}
#main-element2-subelement3{
    display: none;
}



#main-element1:hover ~ main{
    display: block;
}

#main-element2:hover > main{
    display: block;
}


#main-element1-subelement1:hover{
    display: block;
}

#main-element1:hover + #main-element1-subelement2{
    display: block;
}
#main-element1-subelement2:hover{
    display: block;
}

#main-element1:hover + #main-element1-subelement3{
    display: block;
}
#main-element1-subelement3:hover{
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="main-element1">Caso 1. Mismo nivel</div>
<main id="main-element1-subelement1">Elem 1.1</main>
<main id="main-element1-subelement2">Elem 1.2</main>
<main id="main-element1-subelement3">Elem 1.3</main>


<div id="main-element2">Caso 2. Hijos
<main id="main-element2-subelement1">Elem 2.1</main>
<main id="main-element2-subelement2">Elem 2.2</main>
<main id="main-element2-subelement3">Elem 2.3</main>
</div>
```

En [este enlace](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_combinators.asp) encontrarás más información sobre los combinadores de CSS.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, me ha ayudado a entender qué ocurría. Lo estaba haciendo a través de Text Editor en lugar de HTML. Voy a probar a hacer el div a través de un HTML. Muchas gracias!